# How can I return part of array based on selected percentage in PHP?

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is take a list of names (from input), lets say 100, shuffle them, then return a random selection based on a certain percentage (n) of the array.

For example, return 5%, which is 5 random names from the shuffled array if the array had 100 elements (names). I have tried Googling for a solution but couldn't find much and am at a loss and can't get past returning just a shuffled array.

(excerpt)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) === true) {

    $names = $_POST['ShuffleNames'];

    $namesArray = explode("\n", $names);
    shuffle($namesArray);

    //display each name on new line
    foreach($namesArray as $name) {
        echo "<li>". $name . "</li>";
    }

}
```

Comment: why are you checking something that's always a boolean for `=== true`? you can just do `if(isset(..))`

Comment: Take the desired % and multiply by count($namesArray) to get the number of results you need and then convert your foreach() to a for() loop with the count being =< your value from above.

Comment: If you know how many names you have in the array (count($namesArray) will tell you if you don't; then you can work out how many 5% of that is, and use array_slice() to extract that number after shuffling

Comment: You mean because the function returns a boolean value, why do i need === when I could just use if(isset())? Not sure exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

- Accept the user inputs -- the array and percentage
- Count the number of array elements using [`count()`](http://php.net/count)
- Calculate the percentage: (count / percentage) * 100
- Slice the array using [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) and return the result

As a function:

```
function array_percentage($array, $percentage) 
{
    shuffle($array);
    $count = count($array);
    $result = array_slice($array, 0, ceil($count*$percentage/100));
    return $result;
}
```

You can use it like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
    $names = $_POST['ShuffleNames'];
    $namesArray = explode("\n", $names);
    print_r(array_percentage($namesArray, 5));    
}
```

**[Demo!](http://codepad.org/Js9E3U1w)**

Comment: Wow...Perfectly explained. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Almost there but instead of foreach:

```
$max = 5;
for ($i=0;$i<$max;++$i) {
 echo "<li>".array_pop($namesArray). "</li>";
}
```

You can set $max to the percentage you want

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) === true) {

    $x = 5; //Set the percentage

    $names = $_POST['ShuffleNames'];

    $namesArray = explode("\n", $names);
    $total = count($namesArray); //Get the total amount of elements (the 100%)
    shuffle($namesArray);

    //display each name on new line
    for($i = 1; $i <= ($total/100)*$x; $i++) { //loop and output
        echo "<li>". $namesArray[$i] . "</li>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is precisely what I was trying to do. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php

```
$names = $_POST['ShuffleNames'];
    $namesArray = explode("\n", $names);
    $names_Array = **str_shuffle**($namesArray);
    // .. code ...
```